# Is this a PRP? How can I create a distinguisher to show it isn't?

Tags: xor, permutation, pseudo-random-permutation, distinguisher

Consider the keyed permutation $F_k : \{0,1\}^2 \to  \{0,1\}^2$ with two-bit keys defined as $F_k(x) = k\oplus x$.

Is this F a PRP? How can I create a distinguisher D and calculate the difference when using this D?

I know that $F_k(x_1) \oplus x_1$ will give me the key and that all $x$ and $F_k(x)$ in the same permutation use the same key. Can I use this to create a distinguisher?

Comment: Yes. You already got the key to solve the problem. Try to understand the PRP definition again :)